# Converting infix to prefix using a Stack (LinkedList)

Tags: java, collections, stack, prefix, infix-notation

*I am trying to write a method that converts infix to prefix and to do that i want to read a sting reverse and use a stack. When i execute this code i am getting an exception at* `character = expression.charAt(limit);` *how can i fix that code?*

*My input was* **1+3** *and the error i got was:*

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException:
>   String index out of range: 3 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown
>   Source) at PrefixTranslator.translate(PrefixTranslator.java:27) at
>   PrefixTranslatorTest.main(PrefixTranslatorTest.java:11)

PrefixTranslator Class:

```
public class PrefixTranslator
{

static private String expression;
private MyStack<Character> stack = new MyStack<Character>();

//Constructor
public PrefixTranslator(String infixExpression)
{
        expression = infixExpression;
}//End of constructor



public String translate()
{
    //Declare Method Variables
    String input = "";
    String output = "";
    char character = ' ';
    char nextCharacter = ' ';


    for(int limit = expression.length(); limit > 0 ; limit--)
    {
        character = expression.charAt(limit);

        if(isOperator(character))
        {
            output = output + character + " ";
        }   
        else if(character == '(')
        {
            stack.push(character);
        }
        else if(character == ')')
        {
            while(!stack.top().equals('('))
                output = output + stack.pop() + " ";
            stack.pop();
        }
        else
        {
            if(Character.isDigit(character) && (limit + 1) < limit && Character.isDigit(expression.charAt(limit+1)))
            {
                stack.push(character);
                stack.push(expression.charAt(limit+1));
            }
            else if(Character.isDigit(character))
            {
                stack.push(character);
            }   
            else
            {
                output = output + character;
            }
        }
    }//End of for

    while(!stack.isEmpty())
    {
        output = output + stack.pop() + " ";
    }

    return output;
}//End of translate method

//Check priority on characters
public static int precedence(char operator)
{
    if(operator == '+' || operator =='-')
        return 1;
    else if(operator == '*' || operator == '/')
        return 2;
    else
        return 0;
}//End of priority method

public boolean isOperator(char element)
{
    if(element == '*' || element == '-' || element == '/' || element == '+')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}//End of isOperator method

}//End of class
```

PrefixTranslatorTest Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PrefixTranslatorTest{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the expression that you want to convert to prefix.");
        String expression = input.next();
        PrefixTranslator translator = new PrefixTranslator(expression);
        System.out.println(translator.translate());


    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the given input `1+3` `expression.length()` returns `3` and you can refer to indexes `0-2` of that string. So, your loop shouldn't be:

```
for(int limit = expression.length(); limit > 0 ; limit--)
```

And it should be

```
for(int limit = expression.length() - 1; limit >= 0 ; limit--)
```

Comment: now i have another error when i try to convert a expression with a paranthesis like (1+3) it gives another error like   `Exception in thread "main" EmptyStackException: Stack is empty. at PrefixTranslator.translate(PrefixTranslator.java:41)
 at PrefixTranslatorTest.main(PrefixTranslatorTest.java:11)`

Comment: you start from the last character `)`, it enters to `else if(character == ')')` and steps through the while loop there then tries to pop a character from stack. you're at the first char and stack is empty. so the exception is thrown.

Comment: you're welcome. you can refer to the algorithm in this link, it should be easy to convert the algorithm to Java code: http://see-programming.blogspot.com.tr/2013/02/infix-to-prefix-conversion.html

Answer (score 1):

The first index of Java arrays is `0` and the method `length()` returns the number of elements of array. If you need the last element's index, use 
`length() - 1`.

So instead of

```
for (int limit = expression.length(); limit > 0; limit--)
```

use

```
for (int limit = expression.length() - 1; limit >= 0; limit--)
```